# Creating a timer with passing a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I have found/modified an timer that count down to a specific time.

The code so far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function counter() {
var t = "2013-12-01 13:00:00".split(/[- :]/);
var gametime = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
var now = new Date();
var timeDiff = gametime.getTime() - now.getTime();
var timer = setTimeout('counter()');
if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = seconds;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Time remaining: <label id=days></label>:<label id=hours></label>:<label id=mins></label>:<label id=sec></label>
<script type="text/javascript">counter();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where i get stuck so far. What I want is get the time from a database to a PHP variable, and passing it to the t-variable in the javascript.

What I imagined could be done is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function counter() {
var variable = <? echo (json_encode($variable)) ?>;
var t = variable.split(/[- :]/);
var gametime = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
var now = new Date();
var timeDiff = gametime.getTime() - now.getTime();
var timer = setTimeout('counter()');
if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = seconds;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Time remaining: <label id=days></label>:<label id=hours></label>:<label id=mins></label>:<label id=sec></label>
<?php $variable = "2013-12-01 13:00:00";?>
<script type="text/javascript">counter();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But that's just remove the timer. The data is probably not passed i'm guessing? Anybody got an idea for me to get past this?

Comment: json_encode will make it into a JSON object. What does view source reveal for the value of "<? echo (json_encode($variable)) ?>".

Comment: `json_encode()` is the correct way to handle this, since `$variable` is a string and the output will be a correctly formatted JavaScript string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `$variable` after using it. Move

```
<?php $variable = "2013-12-01 13:00:00";?>
```

before

```
var variable = <? echo (json_encode($variable)) ?>;
```

Comment: Heh yeah that might have been a good idea to try that for me first. I also saw i'm missing a php in the tag before Json_encode

But works now so i can get on with it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3053375, as long as short tags are enabled, the `php` in `<?php` is optional.

Comment: Not in this case. That PHP in this script is somehow the difference of the timer showing itself or just a blank page.

Comment: @user3053375, then short tags are likely not enabled. It's always good practice to use `<?php` instead of `<?` if you don't know what the server configuration will be, for exactly this purpose.